# How do I create a Named Docker Data Volumes with data shared with host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

How can I create a shared named volume using the Version 2.1 Docker Compose syntax. I want to mount a host folder as a shared volume and persist the data on the host between shutdowns.

```
web:
< ----- remainder of service defn omitted for clarity ----->
  # Load the external volume 'pgdata' into the folder /var.. on the host
  volumes:
    - pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


# Top level volumes key allows sharing of volume across multiple services
# Volumes defined as name: <path on host>
volumes:
  # Volume named pgdata is located here on the host
  pg-data: #/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  # App data volume
  app-data: #./scribl/
  # Static files volume
  static-data: #./static/
```

Update:
The key thing I'm looking for is the ability to specify the location of the shared volume on the host, i.e. the same as the old method but with named containers

```
volumes:
  - location/on/host:location/on/container
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alrighty, after much searching through the git issues list, we have:

[Github Issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19990)

the implementation looks like this, where volumes is the top level command:

```
volumes:
  # Volume named pgdata is located here on the host
  pg-data: #/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      device: /var/lib/postgres/ # this is the mount path on the host
      o: bind
```

**Edit:**
Device path must be an absolute path -> there's a whole lot of back and forth with the docker devs about this

Answer (score 1):

"Named volumes" and "specify the mount point on the host" are mutually exclusive options. It might be *possible* to do it (as some people have tried with a series of commands in the Github issue you linked) but it's really not a common use case so it shouldn't be *needed* or even generally *recommended*.

The point of a named volume is to be able to persist & reuse (mount into another container) data by giving the data volume a name so you know what's in it. That way when you start another container you can do something like `-v my-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql` without specifying a mount point on your host machine. If you're specifying a mount point for the volume on your host machine, you don't need a named volume because you already have a name (*the path*) and you can even examine the contents. The "name" is the "host mount point".

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, but the named syntax makes the definition of shared volumes that map to a network drive cleaner